# android bitmap "no resource found error"

Tags: android, bitmap

i have **bg.xml** and **texture.png** in **res/drawable folder**.

**bg.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/texture"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

in my layout file i use it as

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">
```

and in design screen no rendering problems occur and virtual device shows the background image (texture.png) properly.

but when i run the app

**No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/texture').**

error happens.

what might be the problem?

Comment: `what might be the problem?` You don't have a file named `texture.png` or `texture.xml` in your `drawable` folder.

Comment: try do clean to your project, then do rebuild your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My image was .jpg and i just changed extension to .png.
Later i used **paint** save as png and updated the image in the drawable folder.
That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure you have a `texture.png` in one of your drawable folder (`.png` or what you prefer).
2. Try to clean your project via Studio or the Gradle console (there is also an option if you're on Eclipse)
3. (**On Studio only**) There is an menu called `restart and invalidate cache`, use it if the step 1 and 2 didn't solve your issue